# base64 canvas webgl object is blank

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I am trying to print a canvas webgl object which is generated in my HTML .

The HTML DOM:

```
     <canvas id="__viewer0-canvas" class="scroller " width="818" height="423" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px); -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; width: 818px !important; height: 423px !important; "></canvas>
```

I am using the following to get the objects dataURL

```
      $('#__viewer0-canvas')[0].toDataURL();
```

But the base64 just gives a blank image when i tried to convert it to image in http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Is it possible to get a 2D image of the webgl canvas object?

Answer (score 1):

First set `{preserveDrawingBuffer: true}`

Example

```
var ctx= canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
```

Second you need to wait until it loaded

```
var imgSrcBase64 = null;

var img = new Image();

img.onload = function(){

// call any thing you want here 

}; 

img.src = $('#__viewer0-canvas')[0].toDataURL();
```

Try it.